# using Cpack w/ verbose output option if i am using cmake -> CMakeLists.txt -> CPackconfig.cmake -> cpackdeb?

Tags: cmake, packaging, deb, cpack

If i was running `cpack` alone through command line, i would add  `cpack -V` for verbose output through options

currently when i run `cmake`, it runs through `CMakeLists.txt` and generates its .deb installer from there. While i'm able to see the verbose output for `cmake` with `cmake --verbose`, I'm not sure how to enable verbosity through `cpack` since the process is automated and not through the command line.

I tried adding `SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEBUG ON)` into my `Cmakelists.txt` but I don't think it's the same as `cpack --verbose`. I can't seem to find anything in the official [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) for a variable that would **enable verbose cpack output**.

I wanted to output my `cpack` verbosely through CMakeList.txt/.cmake, how would I do that?